# if there is duplicate data the how to select the specific one in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table program_data in mysql database.

```
  _id     value
  1        0 
  2        1
  3        3
  4        1
  5        1
  6        1
  7        6
  8        1
  9        2
```

Now here I want to select a single row  whose value is 1. But the twist is, I wanted to select the third 1 from bottom in value column.

The output like:

```
_id = 5  value = 1
```

I have written a query like:

```
 SELECT distinct * FROM program_data  WHERE value= 1 ORDER BY value desc                
  limit  3;
```

But in this case a get the last 3 rows, But I want only one row whose third value is 1 from bottom.

Answer (score 3):

If you wan the third 1 from the "bottom", assuming that `_id` determines the ordering:

```
select d.*
from data d
where value = 1
order by _id desc
limit 2, 1;
```

This uses an offset in the `limit` clause.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using this query. Here is the SQLFIDDLE [Third value](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7055f/1)

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
 SELECT _id,value
 FROM data
 where value = 1 
 ORDER BY _id ASC
 LIMIT 3
) AS tbl
ORDER BY _id DESC
LIMIT 1
```